# Facing error while working with Aggregate function in MDX (MultiDimensional-Expresson)

Tags: ssas, mdx

Hi everyone hope you're doing well

I'm using Aggregate function to aggregate the value of my measure
for two specific years as you can see below :

```
select aggregate ({[DimTime].[Year].&[1396] ,[DimTime].[Year].&[1397] },[Measures].[IndentCount]) on 0 from [Procurement]
```

according to the fact that aggregate function accepts two parameters :

```
Aggregate (Set_expression , Numeric_Expression)
```

What is wrong with my MDX query?

I get this error :

```
The Axis0 function expects a tuple set expression for the  argument. A string or numeric expression was used.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look again at the details for the [Aggregate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/id-id/sql/mdx/aggregate-mdx?view=sql-server-2017) function. You got the parameters correct, but you need to look at **what the function will return**. It returns a numeric value.

So your MDX evaluates as `SELECT some-numeric-value ON 0 FROM [Cube]` which is not valid.

You need `SELECT some-sort-of-set ON 0 FROM [Cube]`

Try googling for examples of using this function (or see link above, which includes examples) to see how it can be used.